# Dynamic Google Search with Python/C#

Tags: python, c#, beautifulsoup, python-requests, google-search

I want to retrieve the Google search result count ( 106,000,000 results (0.58 seconds) ). I wrote this script in Python:

```
import requests, webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_input = input("Type in query: ")
print("Googling..")
link = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + user_input
google_search = requests.get(link)
print(google_search.headers)

#print it out as file

with open("Output.html", "w") as text_file:
    print("{}".format(google_search.text), file=text_file)
```

But when I look in the file, the result stats are just missing. Is there any way to do this other than the Google Search API, which sucks because it is limited and doenst even get the right results.
I wrote Python and C# because I know both.

Comment: Which result stats are you specifically looking for? The result count below the search bar `About 106,000,000 results (0.58 seconds)`? Or counting the links on the page?

Comment: Yes I meant that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. Or you can test `css` selectors with it if you don't like doing it in the dev tools console via `$$('SELECTOR')` command.

Using `css` selectors is more flexible and more readable, try to use [`select_one()` or `select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `bs4` methods indead of `find()`/`findAll()`. `CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Also, you can pass URL query [`params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) like so:

```py
params = {
  'q': 'the most amazing query in 2021',
  'gl': 'hl',
}

requests.get(YOUR_URL, params=params)
```

---

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

user_input = input("Type in query: ")
print(f"Googling... {user_input}")

params = {
  'q': user_input,
  'gl': 'hl',
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params).text, 'lxml')

print(f"Found {soup.select_one('#result-stats').text}"
      .replace("About", "about")
      .replace(" (", " in ")
      .replace(")", ""))

---------
'''
Type in query: fus ro dah
Googling... fus ro dah
Found about 628,000 results in 0.36 seconds 
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference in your particular example is that you don't need to figure out why certain things aren't working as expected since it's already done for the end-user. The only thing that should be done in this case is to grab needed data from the structured JSON string.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

user_input = input("Type in query: ")
print(f"Googling... {user_input}")

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": user_input,
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(f"Total results: {results['search_information']['total_results']}\n"
      f"Time taken: {results['search_information']['time_taken_displayed']}")

-------
'''
Type in query: fus ro dah
Googling... fus ro dah
Total results: 663000
Time took: 0.59 sec
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain correct results from Google, you have to set correct `User-Agent` http header:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


user_input = input("Type in query: ")
print("Googling for keyword={}..".format(user_input))

params = {
    'q': user_input,
    'hl': 'en'   # <-- set hl=en to obtain english only results.
}
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'
}

google_search = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(google_search.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('#result-stats').text)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Type in query: moon
Googling for keyword=moon..
About 1,720,000,000 results (0.99 seconds)
```